# Omit disambiguation results from wbsearchentities

Tags: wikidata, wikidata-api

I'm looking to do a fuzzy text search for entities in wikidata and would like to prevent the "disambiguation" results from being returned by the server.

http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=abc&language=en&limit=3&format=jsonfm

Is there an undocumented parameter or endpoint better suited to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not that I'm aware of, so the solution I use on my project is to filter on the `instance of` ([P31](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P31)) property.

You may already be doing that, but for the record, that gives the following workflow

1. find relevant entities with `wbsearchentities`
2. find their claims with `wbgetentities`
3. keep only entities that don't have [Q4167410](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4167410) (Wikimedia disambiguation page) in their P31 claims

In my case, at 3, I do the opposite: I only keep instances of Q571 (books) or a few other relevant entities